# Firebase document id sort by date?

Tags: swift, firebase

My app has messaging function and I put my messages in the database with the code below:

`Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(uid).collection("chats").document(otherUsername).collection("messages").document(newMessageId).setData(data)`

When i fetch all messages of all users, i want them to be sorted by date. My individual messages are sorted by date, but my message list is sorted by alphabetical order of user ids because of "document(uid)" part of the code. How can i fetch all the messages by date in this situation?

Comment: Use `orderBy()`.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data?hl=en

Comment: *When i fetch all messages of all users* based on the code in your question, you won't be able to fetch messages of all users because the path shown in the question is only for one user; `.document(uid).collection("chats").document(otherUsername).collection("messages")`. You may want to clarify the question and/or the code to more clearly indicate what you are trying to do. Including a screen shot of your Firestore and your code (as text) would probably help get you an answer.